# Outlook 2016 - no envelope icons showing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, icons

I have just downloaded Outlook 2016 - but I cannot see any envelope icons within the mailbox - against each email.  I have set it up to show in the taskbar - that's fine.  But when looking at my mailbox the envelope icons against each email are missing.  I just can't find out how to get them to show - all the other mail icons are working - the urgent, reminder, attachment - but no envelopes.  Any ideas?  Or are they just not part of the set up anymore.
Thanks
Teri

Comment: A screen shot would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Envelope icons in the message list is something that's now working different. For ordinary incoming emails you don't see any icon at all. But you can see the envelope icon (with arrow) when forwarding/replying **in the right** part:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just worked out how to get the unread envelope icon back - click on view - add columns.  Add 'Read' to your list of columns.